# SQL for reading records in between

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following data on databse.

```
ID  |SOURCE|DATETIME          | URL                          | TRANSACTION_ID 
1001|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domain.com/page1.html|NULL
1001|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domain.com/page3.html|NULL
1305|333|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainx.com/page5.html|NULL
1432|777|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainx.com/page5.html|NULL
1001|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domain.com/page5.html|NULL
1001|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domain.com/page2.html|NULL
1001|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domain.com/page1.html|457899447
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page1.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page3.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page5.html|NULL
1005|124|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainx.com/page5.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page2.html|NULL
1005|214|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainx.com/page5.html|NULL
1005|219|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainx.com/page5.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page1.html|1235642321
```

What I want to do is based on the transaction id and SOURCE get the rows in between.
So If want records after the last transaction (457899447) and before the new transaction(1235642321) with example query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SOURCE=254 && TRANSACTION_ID=1235642321
```

I should get the result below

```
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page1.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page3.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page5.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page2.html|NULL
1003|254|2011-01-01 12:00:00|http://www.domainb.com/page1.html|1235642321
```

How can I acomplish this?

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server has a `&&` operator.

Comment: Mysql has :) it was example mate.

Comment: You tagged the question tsql. That's the SQL Server dialect of SQL. If you are using MySQL, tag your question MySQL.

Comment: Why people forget to add such an easy thing like an `IDENTITY` field...? :-( Physical order should not be trusted, period.

Comment: You should edit your subject to remove 'TSQL' since it's not MSSQL you're after.

Comment: @Shift: So, is this for MySQL or MS SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Based on some assumptions based soley on what the small sample of data looks like:

- The "Source" to filter on is the same as that found for the Transaction_Id passed in
- Column "Id" is an ascending integer for all entries in the table for that Source

I come up with:
(updated based on new data)

```
   WITH cteNew (Id, Source)
     as (--  Get Id and Source of transaction @Transaction_Id
         select Id, Source
          from MyTable
          where Transaction_Id = @TransactionId)
    SELECT *  
     from Mytable
      where Source = cteNew.Source  --  All entries for this source
       and Id = cteNew.Id
```

I made it a cte in the hopes that the SQL optimizer will opitimize the redundant queries (table scans), but you could break it into two queries with the first assigning Id and Source to local variables.

(Couldn't test it, some syntax debugging may be required.)

---

Edited, based on comments with @Chris Lively:

If it is the simpler situation, then a simple subquery like so should work--and MySQL supports these, doesn't it?

```
SELECT * 
 from Mytable 
 where Id = (select Id
              from MyTable
              where Transaction_Id = @TransactionId)
```

This assumes (again) that Transaction_ID is unique within the table.

Comment: I have to test this mate. Thanks. I will post my results.

Comment: @Philip: I think you were close.  Check out the updates to the data.  The ID column defines a particular set of transactions.  In this case ID=1003.  I changed your CTE to reflect this

Comment: @Chris: True, but if so, then it looks like all you'd have to do is select all for that ID for that Transaction_ID. Perhaps it is that simple? Can't tell without knowing the rules for how data is loaded in the table.

Comment: @Philip: I think it is that simple.  You just have to grab the ID based on the passed in transaction in order to pull the related records.  I'm still trying to figure out if this is for MySql or MSSQL.  If the former, then there will need to be a different route.

Comment: Added a variant to my original answer based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use

`WHERE ... AND (TRANSACTION_ID=1235642321 OR TRANSACTION_ID IS NULL)`

or:

`WHERE ... AND COALESCE(TRANSACTION_ID,12345642321)=1235642321`

Comment: I need to this also without giving a SOURCE or TRANSACTION_ID. Like group by thing. SO one query that combines all result like example output above.

Comment: I am not sure I get this.. you mean a `TRANSACTION_ID BETWEEN 457899447 AND 1235642321` or you need to detect the previous transaction or..? can you tweak up a little your example output?